# Why does React copy default checkbox value to attributes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

[live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/qx9or532j9)

In this example you see a simple React element (an `<input>`) which does not have any properties except `type` and `id`, it is rendered into a root element (`<div id=root>`) using react-dom. For some reason both defaultValue and value get initialised with 'on' on the actual DOM element. Why does this happen? Is this a bug I should report?

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

const checkboxNoValue = React.createElement('input', {
  type: 'checkbox',
  'id': 'checkboxElement'
});

ReactDOM.render(checkboxNoValue, root);

console.assert(
  checkboxElement.value === 'on',
  'value should return "on" by HTML spec, instead got: '
  + JSON.stringify(checkboxElement.value)
) // this works fine

console.assert(
  checkboxElement.getAttribute('value') === null,
  'value attribute should be empty, instead got: '
    + JSON.stringify(checkboxElement.getAttribute('value'))
)
console.assert(
  checkboxElement.defaultValue === '',
  'defaultValue should be empty, instead got: '
    + JSON.stringify(checkboxElement.defaultValue)
)
```

**EDIT**

In first edit of the question I assumed that `.value` property of `HTMLInputElement` also should be empty; this is not true, it actually must return 'on' if not set otherwise: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-input-value-default-on

Comment: i'm guessing so that it can serialize it appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's actually [a bug](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11998) and this should be fixed in the early 2018 release of React.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue with React itself. This is how the browser behaves by default.

From MDN:

> If the value attribute was omitted, the default value for the checkbox
>   is on.

Full info about the checkbox element:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Comment: The problem is that by spec, only `value` must return 'on', defaultValue and value attribute must not. I've corrected my example to follow the spec, thanks!

Comment: I don't see why the first and second asserts should be different. You are getting the same 'value' using two different methods, so both should be 'on' in this case. Bear in mind that you're getting them both from the actual DOM element, not the React element.

For the defaultValue, it's true that non-react input elements set it to empty string if value is not set, so React may be setting it. I don't know if this is by design.